# How to record audio in Ableton?

Tags: ableton

How do i record audio from mic with **Ableton** Live?
Mic is connected to Line-In port of external audio card, card itself is recognized perfectly as i can hear VST's and such;

Comment: Is the track armed?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Preferences and make sure your audio interface is selected for input. You can select a different interface for input and output, so being able to hear VSTs coming out your interface doesn't ensure that Ableton is configured correctly. Also note that if you start Ableton up with the audio interface unplugged, Ableton will forget about it, and you will have to select it again.
2. Pick an Audio track, or create a new one
3. Click the Record button at the bottom of the track - this is the rectangle with a circle in it.
4. Use the Audio From boxes to select your audio interface and the correct input. If you make some noise into the mic, you should see the meter bounce around in resposne.
5. Hit the record button at the top of the screen to arm recording
6. Hit the play button to actually start recording.

Answer (score 0):

[image: This shows the record enabled track]One thing that may help you that no-one has pointed out (sorry if you have already done this) is have you got your track record-ready?

Comment: Actually, both my comment on the question and Obscure's answer referenced this.